# Why is the Slide Deck of my web page not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the HTML 5 boiler plate in the creation of my website. I am using the JQuery slide deck plug-in as well as the JQuery pretty photo plug-in. In boiler plate javascrit files are place at the bottom of the page but this causes the slide deck plug-in stop work.

When I include the plug-ins at the top of the page, it works properly but when placed at the bottom it stops. the include order it the same in both cases: Jquery is loaded first than the plug-in. The HTML that follows is the one that is working. At the bottom of the page I have commented out the none working code.

I know that the HTML 5 boiler plate has a script files for all script initiation code, and a plug-ins file for all plug-ins code. But I have yet to get the plug-ins that I have used by placing them in these files. Any help would be great.

---

```
    <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Basics - A blog and magazine template</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidedeck.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidedeck.ie.css">

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>


    <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
    <!--<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slidedeck.js"></script>
    <!-- end scripts-->


</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

        <!-- Slider -->
        <div id="sliderSection">

                <div class="cAlign">

                    <div id="slidedeckFrame" class="skin-slidedeck">

                        <dl class="slidedeck">
                            <dt>Slide 1 name</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/190/190/abstract" alt="Abstract" class="borderImg" /></a>

                                <h1>This is slide 1</h1>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>

                                <div class="blankSeparator"><!-- --></div>

                                <p><a class="buttonLink" href="#">Read more about this</a></p>
                            </dd>

                            <dt>Slide 2</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/190/190/abstract" alt="Abstract" class="borderImg" /></a>

                                <h1>This is slide 1</h1>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. </p>

                                <div class="blankSeparator"><!-- --></div>

                                <p><a class="buttonLink" href="#">Read more</a></p>
                            </dd>

                            <dt>Slide 3</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <h1>This is slide 3</h1>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
                            </dd>

                            <dt>Slide 4</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <h1>This is slide 4</h1>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>   

                        <!-- Activate the slider -->
                        <script>
                            $('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
                        </script>

                    </div> <!-- end skin-slidedeck -->      

                </div> <!-- end cAlign -->

            </div> <!-- end of sliderSection -->

      </div> <!-- end of #container -->


  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>-->


  <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <!--<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slidedeck.js"></script>
  <!-- end scripts-->


  <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="js/libs/dd_belatedpng.js"></script>
    <script>DD_belatedPNG.fix("img, .png_bg");</script>
  <![endif]-->


  <script>
    var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID 
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
    g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically, what we will do here anyways, is to nerf the code down. Take out the unnecessary things to see things more clear. So if we have to do so anyways, why not do it yourself? Nerf down all unnecessary elements, leave only those that we need for problem. Also, remove or replace all local files like "img/mypicture.jpg". We don't have access to them. I do have ideas, what might be the problem, but at the moment you are asking us to program for you. Please respect our time and nerf the code down :)

Comment: I have isolates the HTML down to just the slide deck. I believe that the problem lyes in that the slide deck JS calls the css to action first and if the JS is called after the DOM is built it dose not work but I am not to wise on JS I am just styling the slide deck and leaving it as is. Do I need to give you the slide deck JS code as well. The placement of the includes is what I ma having problems with. It throughs off the functionality of the plug-in. What I would like to do in the end is just past all my JS files in the plug-ins file that comes with the HTML5 boiler plate.

Comment: Well, there are still much more code then needed (example: google analytics.) But Things are getting more clear. Yes, of course you need to provide the JS, because as far as I understand, the problem is in the JS. But I really think, the best would be to provide a live demo?! With all the local files. I bet you will get your answer 80% faster :)

Comment: ok I have placed a demo of the slide show and the attached JS files are commented out on the bottom of the page and at the top of the page they are uncommented out. Currently it works but when I place the JS at the bottom of the page it stops working? http://epecho.com/tst/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ok see the difference between copying the code and live demo. Actually, I should have spotted the issue right away.. But my eyes work better on my own editors colors.*

Your problem probably was that you added the slidedeck.js in the footer. It must sit in the header. I would strongly recomend after jquery. And jquery must also sit in the header and not in the footer.

**http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6972756.php**

As you can see everything is working fine. You cannot add plugins to footer, you can add functions.js etc in the footer, but not jquery and plugins.

**Full working code**

*(By the way, this is how you nerf the code from unnecessary stuff)*

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <base href="http://epecho.com/tst/">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidedeck.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidedeck.ie.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slidedeck.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
        <div id="sliderSection">
                <div class="cAlign">
                    <div id="slidedeckFrame" class="skin-slidedeck">
                        <dl class="slidedeck">
                            <dt>Slide 1 name</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/190/190/abstract" alt="Abstract" class="borderImg" /></a>
                                <h1>This is slide 1</h1>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>
                                <div class="blankSeparator"><!-- --></div>
                                <p><a class="buttonLink" href="#">Read more about this</a></p>
                            </dd>
                            <dt>Slide 2</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/190/190/abstract" alt="Abstract" class="borderImg" /></a>
                                <h1>This is slide 1</h1>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>

                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. </p>
                                <div class="blankSeparator"><!-- --></div>
                                <p><a class="buttonLink" href="#">Read more</a></p>
                            </dd>
                            <dt>Slide 3</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <h1>This is slide 3</h1>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

                            </dd>
                            <dt>Slide 4</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <h1>This is slide 4</h1>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>   
                        <script>
                            $('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if you got it. But leave the slidedeck.js on top and the functions.js in footer :)

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the build script that comes with the HTML5 boiler plate. I would like to keep my JS separate from my HTML. boiler plate has to JS files one to put your initiation scripts and one to put all your plug-ins scripts.

Comment: Well, technically your original problem got solved. And you can put your plugins into one place and keep the calling functions in the footer as I explained above.

Comment: I changed my answer. Make sure that `<script src="js/slidedeck.js"></script>` is in the header and not in the footer and everything will work fine.